# How to generate app-unsigned.apk in Ionic?

Tags: android, ionic4

I'm using `ionic cordova build android --prod --release --key=keystoreName.keystore` to build Ionic unsigned APK in Ionic 4.

Answer (score 0):

Just use command

```
ionic cordova build android
```

That's it.